# `+': no implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

Getting this error:

```
(`+': no implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError))
```

This is the line calling it:

```
print "\tsize "+(package["size"] == nil ? "" : package["size"])+"\n";
```

Comment: `package["size"]` is an Integer. Change it to `package["size"].to_s` or use string interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `package["size"]` is not nil, its returning and integer and you're trying to concatenate it into a string, and its not doing implicite typcasting of values

Here are a few ways you can get it to work

Solution 1.

```
"\tsize " + package['size'].to_s + "\n";
```

Solution 2.

```
"\tsize #{package['size'].to_s}\n";
```

Comment: @Kumar - why not use `"\tsize " + (package['size']).to_s + "\n"` directly?

Comment: In solution 2, no need to use `.to_s`, it's implicit.